# ggplot2's mpg dataset--what's the "fl." variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataset

In **ggplot2**'s built-in mpg dataset there is variable called "fl.", which is a factor with levels: "c", "d", "e", "p", & "r".

Does anyone know what those letters are supposed to stand for? Needless to say, googling those letters has yet to give me any relevant leads...

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)
str(mpg)
?mpg
```

[Note: There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617174/r-mtcars-dataset-meaning-of-vs-variable) on SO re: the **mtcars** dataset, which gave me the impression that this would be an appropriate forum for this sort of question.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fuel:

- e: ethanol E85, note(`subset(mpg, fl=="e")` pulls up only "new" american cars, and that fuel economy is much lower than the corresponding presumably gasoline models, which lines up with the lower energy content of ethanol)
- d: diesel
- r: regular
- p: premium
- c: CNG (note as far as I know the civic is basically [the only passenger car that runs on CNG](http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/bifueltech.shtml) in the US).

Note, I have no reason to know this other than an educated guess based on the rest of the data, but here is some graphical evidence:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=fl, y=hwy)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~cyl, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Notice how `e` is consistently low `d` is consistently high at least where there is more than 1 data point (diesel has higher energy content) and `p` is consistently higher than `r` (premium allows cars to run at higher compression ratios and efficiency, though actually premium has lower energy content than regular) for each cylinder category (facets are # of cylinders).

---

**UPDATE**: as per @naught101, this now appears to be [documented](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/mpg.html).

Comment: Nailed it. This was really bugging me... Thanks.

Comment: @rawr, missed that one, but presumably **[CNG](http://newsok.com/oklahoma-energy-3-things-ive-learned-from-owning-my-first-cng-vehicle/article/3867155)**.

Comment: And you gotta +1 me for that one ;)

Comment: @rawr: I think it might be something like "combined"--possibly representing that **E85** blend...

Comment: @SteveS almost certain it's CNG

Comment: Yeah, I gave you a +1... But because you answered so quickly, I wasn't allowed to accept your answer (you still have to wait)...

Comment: Oh, ok--that makes sense--so would **e** be "E85", then?

Comment: document your data, hadley

Comment: @SteveS, yes that's what I meant by ethanol.

Comment: @rawr, want to add an @ before Hadley's name in your comment? ;)

Comment: Thanks again--"mpg" & "mtcars" have really reminded me just how little I know about cars...

Comment: @SteveS, also, the "you gotta give me +1" was facetiously targeted at rawr for being pesky about the `c`, not you.

Comment: For the record, I gave you the **+1** *before* that comment.

Comment: I dont think @hadley works unless he has posted in this thread?

Comment: @rawr, that would make sense, didn't know that.

Comment: well some of that stuff are interesting/useful things I have gathered from SO or other places and amended to my liking and documented. I'm not *that* useful (yet) in r, but thanks for assuming :}

Comment: e == e95 is correct. The data is from Fueleconomy.gov (see [the dataset's docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/mpg.html)). So, for instance the rows mpg[19:20,] correspond to the two different efficiencies for [this car](https://fueleconomy.gov/feg/Find.do?action=sbs&id=24707) (according to the manufacturer, year, make, and transmission).

Comment: Thanks @naught101.  Looks like Hadley listened to rawr.

Comment: Yeah. It would still be nice if it was explicitly documented at that page, @hadley. Or even better, replaced with a meaningful value, like 'e95' (note that the FuelEconomy.gov dataset now includes electric vehicles, and gives them an MPG equivalent rating, so 'e' is more ambiguous).